# ASP.NET MVC - TextArea values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a WYSIWYG editor set up using ASP.NET MVC.  When I post, everything is fine, however when I post and there is an error when the page comes back and shows the errors, the value in the textbox is messed up (it has become un-HTML Encoded) and for form validation reasons, this is fine.
My question is this - how, in the controller (preferably), can I change the value of the text in the textarea?  Even if I use a ViewData["fieldname"] and set the asp code to:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("fieldname", ViewData["fieldname"], new { id = "fieldthing", name = "fieldthing", cols = "80", rows = "10" })%>
```

It still doesn't work because that ViewData is the *default value* which, after the post, isn't returned to that value, it stays whatever was typed.

So any thoughts on how to edit this value?  I tried passing in a new view, but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you've detected an error in your Controller, are you *resetting* the value of `ViewData["fieldname"]`  to be the same value as `fieldname`?

Consider implementing something like this, if it helps:

```
if (!SanityCheckUserInput())
{
  //something didn't pass validation. send back to user for correction
  ViewData["fieldname"] = Request.Form["fieldname"];
  return View(); //return the same View
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On post, the ModelState will hold the posted value and use that to repopulate the form if returning to the same page (validation failure). If you don't want to do that, try `ModelState.Remove("fieldthing");`